# How to reference StringExpression named parts from a package without full Context path?

Tags: programming, string-manipulation, packages

I have a long `StringExpression` in a package returned by a function. There are some named parts in the expression that I would like to reference when I use the package.

```
BeginPackage["FindStuff`"]

BigStringExpr::usage="A big StringExpression with named parts."

Begin["`Private`"]

BigStringExpr[]:= StartOfString ~~ someLetters: ToUpperCase@Alphabet[] .. ~~ "@" ~~ anInteger: (Except["0", DigitCharacter] ~~ DigitCharacter ...) ~~ EndOfString

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

When I load this package I can get the string expression but the named parts have the complete context path.

```
<< FindStuff`
BigStringExpr[]
(* StartOfString ~~ 
 FindStuff`Private`someLetters : ({"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
     "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", 
     "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"} ..) ~~ "@" ~~ 
 FindStuff`Private`anInteger : (Except["0", DigitCharacter] ~~ 
    DigitCharacter ...) ~~ EndOfString *)
```

To use the named parts from the package I have to specify the complete context path.

```
StringCases["ADSDG@1234", BigStringExpr[] -> {someLetters, anInteger}]
(* {{someLetters, anInteger}} *)

StringCases["ADSDG@1234", BigStringExpr[] -> {FindStuff`Private`someLetters, FindStuff`Private`anInteger}]
(* {{"ADSDG", 1234}} *)
```

Is there a way to simply reference `someLetters` and `anInteger` from `BigStringExpr[]` without the full context path for the named parts?  I have tried `Evaluate@BigStringExpr[]` without any luck.

Comment: many of the symbolic Mathematica functions have the same problem, the standard way to solve it is to pass the symbols to be used as variables in a second argument...

Comment: @AlbertRetey I tried `BigStringExpr[someLetters_Symbol, anInteger_Symbol]:= StartOfString ~~ someLetters: ToUpperCase@Alphabet[] .. ~~ "@" ~~ anInteger: (Except["0", DigitCharacter] ~~ DigitCharacter ...) ~~ EndOfString`.  It complains that the symbols already appear on the right-hand side.  How would you pass in the symbols? May you provide and answer post, please.

Comment: You want something like `bigStringExpr[someLetters_Symbol, anInteger_Symbol] := With[{sl = someLetters, int = anInteger },
  StartOfString ~~ Pattern[sl, ToUpperCase@Alphabet[] ..] ~~ "@" ~~ 
   Pattern[int, (Except["0", DigitCharacter] ~~ DigitCharacter ...)] ~~
    EndOfString]`, where `With` serves to full the system and avoid those complaints.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Yes, in the mean time I kept looking and found out that they were warning (not error) messages.  I turned them off with `Off[RuleDelayed::rhs]` in the package just before defining `BigStringExpr` and then turned them back on with `On[RuleDelayed::rhs]` immediately after. Thanks for the pass in the symbols idea. Making an answer post?

Comment: Well, the main point was coming from @AlbertRetey, so I'd rather see his answer here - I just gave a small technical hint.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: I didn't actually plan to give an answer, but your comment made me feel I have to :-)

Comment: That's great, @AlbertRetey, thanks! I wouldn't have produced such a nice answer for sure, so I am glad to have asked you to do this. I hope this didn't take too much time from you.

Comment: everything always takes too much time, but I'm enjoying the freedom to waste my time as I like :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to a common problem that many symbolic Mathematica functions share, e.g.:

```
Solve[2*x-5==15,x]
```

and as can be seen from the example the standard way to solve that is to pass such symbols which are to be used as formal symbols as extra argument(s). As you guessed in your comment the most direct way to implement that would be something like:

```
BigStringExpr[someLetters_Symbol, anInteger_Symbol] := 
  StartOfString ~~ someLetters : ToUpperCase@Alphabet[] .. ~~ "@" ~~ 
  anInteger : (Except["0", DigitCharacter] ~~ DigitCharacter ...) ~~ 
  EndOfString
```

which does work, as can be verified with e.g.:

```
StringReplace["ABC@123", BigStringExpr[a, b] :> StringJoin[b, "---", a]]
```

A remaining problem is, as you have noted, that a warning is issued at definition time and the syntax highlighting indicates the two names as a syntax error. That message and syntax error are there for understandable reasons as such definitions often not do what users actually want. But in this case it does exactly why we want, so we can safely ignore these warnings.

You found yourself one way to suppress the message, which of course is to just (temporarily) switch off that message with `Off[RuleDelayed::rhs]` (and switch back on with `On` after the definition). Newer versions provide the `Quiet` function to provide exactly the possibility to "temporarily" switch off messages which is shorter and has the advantage to reset the originial state, no matter whether that was on or off. Leonid has shown you another version which avoids the message in the first place by inserting the symbols with `With`:

```
bigStringExpr[someLetters_Symbol, anInteger_Symbol] := 
  With[{sl = someLetters, int = anInteger}, 
    StartOfString ~~ Pattern[sl, ToUpperCase@Alphabet[] ..] ~~ "@" ~~ 
    Pattern[int, (Except["0", DigitCharacter] ~~ DigitCharacter ...)] ~~
    EndOfString]
```

Actually that just "hides" the potential problem from Mathematica so that neither the syntax checker nor the messaging system actually complain. One could see this as just a trick which might fail when a more sophisticated future version of Mathematica will recognize such patterns as "dangerous" as well. So it probably is even cleaner to temporarily switch off the message. That will also be easier to read as it is clear why that part of the code is there at all, where you might have a hard time to find out what the `With` was there when revisiting the code (a corresponding comment would then of course make sense).

One other thing I would improve (which is not directly related to the message/syntax highlighting) is to make that definition work even when there are definitions for the symbols you are using. First note that this won't work:

```
x=1;
BigStringExpr[x, y]
```

With adding:

```
SetAttributes[BigStringExpr,HoldAll]
```

you could make your function work even in that case which will make it somewhat more robust.

So for me the cleanest and most robust way to make such a definition seems to be:

```
Quiet[
  SetAttributes[bigStringExpr,HoldAll];
  bigStringExpr[someLetters_Symbol, anInteger_Symbol] := (
    StartOfString ~~ someLetters : ToUpperCase@Alphabet[] .. ~~ "@" ~~ 
    anInteger : (Except["0", DigitCharacter] ~~ DigitCharacter ...) ~~ 
    EndOfString
  ),
  RuleDelayed::rhs
]
```

You'll have to live with the syntax highlighting, but that seems OK for me as the `Quiet` indicates that someone has noted the problem and decided it was OK to ignore the message (and the highlighting). Depending on the code quality requirements a corresponding comment would make sense...

Comment: A very comprehensive answer. I've taken note of and implemented the `SetAttribute` enhancement.