# FromDigits gives "not a list of digits" error for integer string in StringExpression rule of StringCases

Tags: string-manipulation, conversion

I have large `StringExpression` that is used in `StringCases`.  Some of the parts being pulled out are integer strings.  These pull out fine.  However, when I go to convert them from strings to integers with `FromDigits` (it can take a string of integers) in `StringCases` it errors but still converts the string to an integer. Minimal example:

```
ClearAll[BigStringExpr];
Off[RuleDelayed::rhs];
BigStringExpr[anInteger_Symbol] := 
 StartOfString ~~ 
  anInteger : (Except["0", DigitCharacter] ~~ DigitCharacter ...) ~~ 
  EndOfString
On[RuleDelayed::rhs];

StringCases["1234", BigStringExpr[y] -> y]
(* {"1234"} *)

StringCases["1234", BigStringExpr[y] -> FromDigits@y]
FromDigits::nlst: The expression y is not a list of digits or a string of valid digits. >>
(* {1234} *)
```

Any ideas why this is happening?  I know that I can convert after `StringCases` but I would prefer to keep it in there since it is a simple call and also helps with code readability.

Comment: Use `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) rather than `Rule` (`->`) in your `StringCases`; this will force evaluation of your `FromDigits` function at the opportune time, i.e. when $y$ has been given a value.

Comment: @MarcoB That did it. I have to keep that whole *delayed* thing in mind as I always forget its significance. Executes after replacement. `{x, x} /. x -> RandomReal[]` verses `{x, x} /. x :> RandomReal[]`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[BigStringExpr];
BigStringExpr = (StartOfString ~~ 
    anInteger : (Except["0", DigitCharacter] ~~ DigitCharacter ...) ~~
      EndOfString :> ToExpression@anInteger)
StringCases["1234", BigStringExpr]
Head[%[[1]]]
```

> {1234}
>
> Integer

Comment: Thanks, but I need to define the string expression as I have because it is in a package.  The method I've used allows me to reference the named parts of the expression from the package without using the full context path. See question [91851](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91851).

Comment: @Edmund It is not the question of how you define the string expression that is the problem. It is the use of Rule. george2079 is using RuleDelayed (i.e., :>). This is the key point. This works `StringCases["1234", BigStringExpr[y] :> FromDigits@y]`